# WebStorm, how to disabled "virtual space" in the middle of text?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

This is freaking annoying me. I don't know which option do this, but it is really bothering me so much.

The problem is that WebStorm add a "virtual" space after each text like function or object (picture 1). You can see it because clearly in the highlight text (picture 2).

Also, when I am writing on a line, the text is push right to the caret (picture 3)

I want to know which option is it, to disable it.

[image: freaking space 1]

[image: highlighted text]

[image: push text]

Comment: There is no option for that; the behavior you see is not intended. Please try selecting a different font.

Comment: Please try different font.

Comment: Wow, thank you both, @yole & LazyOne The problem was the font, as you both said. The font in question is SourceCode Pro, for future reference.

If you answer the question I will selected as OK.

Thanks Again!!

Comment: This may also caused by the broken installation of the Source Code Pro font, see the [related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168744), try to reinstall it. Also make sure you run on [JetBrains Runtime](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue for this problem:

- [IDEA-154843](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154843) There is a space coming between cursor and the next letter when typing or the cursor is moved.

It definitely helps to select a different font, but reinstalling the latest version of Source Code Pro font may also help.

[UPDATE](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154843#comment=27-2002342):

> It should be already fixed in latest 2017.1 builds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the tip from user [@yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) & user [@LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone), the problem was the font **"Source Code Pro"**. Changing the font, solve the problem.

As user [@CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) has link this question to an open bug, the next is information for Jetbrains Developers.

- SO: MacOS 10.12.1
- WebStorm version: 2016.3.4 (Download it on 8th March 2017)
- WebStorm plugins: None.